# Electron - Uncaught (in promise) Error: An object could not be cloned

Tags: promise, electron

I've this error when I click on my button:
Uncaught (in promise) Error: An object could not be cloned.

I start with electron, and I would like to take advantage of this topic to know the difference between invoke and send (I tried both, with the same error)

Main.js

```
 ipcMain.handle('savePdf',  (event, pdfFile) => {
    
    console.log(event);
    console.log(pdfFile);
    return pdfFile;
    }
```

preload.js

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('pdf', {
  savePdf: (file) => ipcRenderer.invoke('savePdf', file),
})
```

rendered.js

```
const pdfFileInput = document.getElementById('input-file'); // OK
const pdfFile = pdfFileInput.files[0]; // OK
console.log(pdfFile); // OK
await pdf.savePdf(pdfFile);
```

Comment: electron can't serialize your pdfFile object. What is that object like? If it has functions on it, then that's why